# Python LSP Problems

Tags: python, company-mode, lsp-mode

I am having a strange problem.  I have my `init.el`, `~/.emacs.d/lisp` and a Python file `tcvw.py` synced between two computers running the exact same version of Emacs (27.1) and same OS (Debian Sid).

In one of these computers, all works perfectly, including LSP (using `pyright`).  In the other I LSP is not working when trying to open the Python file.  Two errors occur, although they might be unrelated.

First, when trying to open `tcvm.py`, I am asked if I want to watch files in a different directory (my `www-home`), which has too many files.  This is directory is not a subdirectory of the project (or the other way around), so I have no idea why I am being asked that.  In fact, it happens when I try to open any Python project.  (I am not sure if this has anything to do with LSP not working in Python, though...)

Second, I get error messages:

```
ad-handle-definition: ‘hippie-expand’ got redefined
File local-variables error: (void-variable python-shell-interpreter)
When done with a buffer, type C-x #
Error running timer: (void-variable company-quick-access-hint-function)
Error processing message (void-variable company-quick-access-hint-function). [2 times]
Watching all the files in /home/finotti/GD/www-home would require adding watches to 1071 directories, so watching the repo may slow Emacs down.
Do you want to watch all files in /home/finotti/GD/www-home? (y or n) n
LSP :: You can configure this warning with the `lsp-enable-file-watchers' and `lsp-file-watch-threshold' variables
Error processing message (void-variable company-quick-access-hint-function).
```

and LSP mode does not load.

It was working yesterday (in both computers) and stopped working in one of them while I was working on it.

Here are some (maybe) relevant parts of my `init.el`:

```lisp
;; set up for breadcrumbs on top
(defun lrf/lsp-mode-setup ()
  (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-segments '(path-up-to-project file symbols))
  (lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode))

(use-package lsp-mode
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :hook
  (lsp-mode . lrf/lsp-mode-setup)
  ;; (LaTeX-mode . lsp)
  (web-mode . lsp)
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")  ;; Or 'C-l', 's-l'
  :config
  (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t)
  :commands
  lsp)


(use-package lsp-ui
  :hook
  (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :custom
  ;; (lsp-ui-doc-position 'bottom)
  (lsp-ui-doc-enable nil))



(use-package lsp-treemacs
  :after lsp)


(use-package lsp-ivy)

(use-package company
  :after lsp-mode
  :hook (lsp-mode . company-mode)
  :bind (:map company-active-map
         ("<tab>" . company-complete-selection))
  ;;       (:map lsp-mode-map
  ;;        ("<tab>" . company-indent-or-complete-common))
  :custom
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0))

(use-package company-box
  :hook (company-mode . company-box-mode))

;; Python (pyright): https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-pyright/
(use-package lsp-pyright
  :hook (python-mode . (lambda ()
                          (require 'lsp-pyright)
                          (lsp-deferred))))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you compared the init files on the two computers? How are you syncing them?

Comment: I sync them with Google Drive and [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/).  They are identical.

Comment: I also tried copying only `init.el` and my snippets folder to a new (and empty) `.emacs.d` folder.  The `www-home` folder problem went away, but LSP still doe not load.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `python-shell-interpreter` in each instance? Do `C-h v python-shell-interpreter` to find out. How is it set? Why is it not defined in the non-working instance? How do you set it as a file-local variable?

Comment: @NickD: Thanks for the help!  I added the `python-shell-interpreter` to `init.el` and it did not help.  But, I figured out what was wrong.  `company` was not installed in the second computer.  (I think it was removed when I updated the packages, maybe???)  It's strange, since I have `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)`.  With the old `.emacs.d`, the `www-home` problem remains, though...